# Open text file only once in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have below code which prints text from a column but open a text file many times instead of once. Please let me know what is the wrong.
When I run sub in Visual Basic debug mode, it open text file only once. But I am calling this macro after another macro and that time it is opening (same) text file many times.

```
Sub createdevtest()
Dim filename As String, lineText As String
Dim data As Range
Dim myrng As Range, i, j

' filename = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\textfile-" & Format(Now, "ddmmyy-hhmmss") & ".txt"
 filename = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\devtest" & ".txt"

Open filename For Output As #1
Dim LastRow As Long
'Find the last non-blank cell in column A(1)
 LastRow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("B4:B" & LastRow).Select
Set myrng = Selection

For i = 1 To myrng.Rows.count
    For j = 1 To myrng.Columns.count
        lineText = IIf(j = 1, "", lineText & ",") & myrng.Cells(i, j)
    Next j
    Print #1, lineText
Next i

Close #1
Range("B4").Select
' open devtest
'Shell "explorer.exe" & " " & ThisWorkbook.Path, vbNormalFocus
filename = Shell("Notepad.exe " & filename, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the code of the other macro?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Luuklag. I had tried to figure out on my own but no success. After your comment, just went thru code again and got clue.

Below is the correct code where I have called one of the macro (devtest1) which contains above text file creation macro (createdevtest). Before correction I was calling macro in function instead of Sub, so it was looping again and opening txt file many times.

```
' macro to select folder and list files
Sub GetFileNames_devtest()
Set Folder = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
If Folder.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
xDir = Folder.SelectedItems(1)
Call ListFilesInFolder(xDir, True)

' call devtest: corrected to call macro at right place
devtest1
End Sub
Sub ListFilesInFolder(ByVal xFolderName As String, ByVal xIsSubfolders As Boolean)
Dim xFileSystemObject As Object
Dim xFolder As Object
Dim xSubFolder As Object
Dim xFile As Object
Dim rowIndex As Long
Set xFileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set xFolder = xFileSystemObject.GetFolder(xFolderName)
rowIndex = Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
For Each xFile In xFolder.Files
  Application.ActiveSheet.Cells(rowIndex, 1).Formula = xFile.Name
  rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
Next xFile
If xIsSubfolders Then
  For Each xSubFolder In xFolder.SubFolders
    ListFilesInFolder xSubFolder.Path, True
  Next xSubFolder
End If
Set xFile = Nothing
Set xFolder = Nothing
Set xFileSystemObject = Nothing
'' Was calling wrongly macro here
End Sub
Function GetFileOwner(ByVal xPath As String, ByVal xName As String)
Dim xFolder As Object
Dim xFolderItem As Object
Dim xShell As Object
xName = StrConv(xName, vbUnicode)
xPath = StrConv(xPath, vbUnicode)
Set xShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set xFolder = xShell.Namespace(StrConv(xPath, vbFromUnicode))
If Not xFolder Is Nothing Then
  Set xFolderItem = xFolder.ParseName(StrConv(xName, vbFromUnicode))
End If
If Not xFolderItem Is Nothing Then
  GetFileOwner = xFolder.GetDetailsOf(xFolderItem, 8)
Else
  GetFileOwner = ""
End If
Set xShell = Nothing
Set xFolder = Nothing
Set xFolderItem = Nothing
End Function
End Function
```